# Self join in rails is returning the parent record for each expected child row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-join

I have an Audio model in my rails app, which is using an `id` and parent_audio_id field to build a hierarchy.  A single Audio can be the child of another Audio, or have many children Audios (which I am calling derivatives).

I've referenced [this edge guide on self joins to construct the relationships](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), [and this SO post to help troubleshoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250409/understanding-rails-activerecord-single-model-self-joins)

Using the active record query below, I get a data set with the parent audio data duplicated N times, where N equals the number of child records for that parent.

How can I return the child records for a given parent audio record given a self-join relationship?

```
**Audio.rb**

class Audio < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :derivatives, :class_name => "Audio", :foreign_key => "parent_audio_id"
  belongs_to :parent_audio, :class_name => "Audio", optional: true

end

**Audio Migration**
    class CreateAudios < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
     def change
      create_table :audios do |t|
       t.references :parent_audio, foreign_key: {to_table: :audios}
      end
     end
    end



    **Audios Controller**
     def audio_details
      data = []
      derivatives = Audio.joins(:derivatives)
      data.push(derivatives)
      render json: data
     end
```

I've also tried `derivatives = Derivative.joins(:audios)` but get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Api::V1::AudiosController::Derivative
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.joins` simply adds a `INNER JOIN` to the query. It does not select any columns on the joined table and does not return the association. It returns a new scope based on whatever it was called on - so in this case the scope will select audios that have at least one match in the joined table (at least one descendant).

`.joins` is primarily used for filtering records based on the joined table:

```
Patient.joins(:appointments)
       .where(scheduled_at: Time.current..)
```

Or selecting aggregates:

```
Hotel.joins(:reviews)
     .select('hotels.*', 'AVG(reviews.rating) AS average_rating')
     .group(:id)
```

If you want to return the descendants of a specific Audio you need to call the method generated by the association macro on an instance of the class:

```
@audio = Audio.find(params[:id])
@descendents = @audio.descendents
```

ActiveRecord will automatically create a separate query to load the decedents.

You can use `.eager_load` to force a single query instead of two:

```
@audio = Audio.eager_load(:descendents)
              .find(params[:id])
@descendents = @audio.descendents
```

See [Rails Guides: Active Record Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

Comment: Thanks for laying that out so simply, and adding the eager_load bit.  I read the rails guides docs a few times but it still wasn't exactly clear.